# Techum Shabbos Bizman Hazeh

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Techum Shabbos is the halcha that one may not travel more than 2000 amos out of civilisation. In the Modern world, where everyone is connected the the rest of civilisation through the internet, how far may we travel?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: You call the Internet civilized?

Comment: @msh210 and todays civilization IS?

Answer (score 4):

Aderabah, though many places are settled, fewer of them have computers, and even fewer still are the computers running [Civilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_(series)).

Chazal say that Shabbos is Me'ayn Olam Haba, which, as [Chazal also state](http://ohr.edu/4988) is where the Or HaGanuz is being held for the tzadikim (Chagigah 12b).

Thus, they warn that on Shabbos we must not be too far from the hidden glowing light of Olam Haba as embodied in the video game of Sid Meier/Sod Ma'ir.